# To check whether the function is piecewise continuous or not

Tags: continuity, fourier-analysis, piecewise-continuity

Let 
\begin{equation}
f(x) \triangleq \begin{cases}
           1, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\                  
          -1, & x \notin \mathbb{Q}
       \end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbb{Q}$ denotes the set of rational numbers. The function is definitely discontinuous at every point of the real line( if I am not wrong).

**But I need help regarding piecewise concept of continuity**

Thanks

[image: [The image shows the definition need to be referred]

Comment: What's your definition of "peicewise continuous"? Edit that into the question and tell us what you think.

Comment: Kindly see the picture

Comment: Read and understand the definition in the picture. Then see how to use that understanding to answer your own question. If there is a particular point you don't understand, ask (in the question, not comments) for help with that particular point.

Comment: I guess no matter how small subintervals I do, the function will be discontinuous in each sub interval so the function must not be piecewise continuous. Am I right? Please help me this time. I will keep your words in mind

Comment: Yes, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By definition:

> A function is piecewise continuous if it is continuous on all but a finite number of points.

So if a function is discontinuous at any real number.......

Comment: Is this some official definition? I thought having discontinuities in countably many isolated points is okay too.

Comment: This is the definition  in https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Piecewise_Continuous_Function

Comment: And also in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiecewiseContinuous.html